# Symfony 4 simple form_login not working

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

New to Symfony. I am quite stumped and struggling for hours on this. I am following [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html) "traditional login form" tutorial from the official docs.

Additionally I have also configured to load users from the database with doctrine as showed in [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html). I have imported the database tables from another application but I only needed doctrine for security/authentication stuff.

I have checked all the necessary files and seem to be similar to the one on the tutorial, but still my login form doesn't work. It does not throw out errors or anything. It just fails silently, whenever I click on submit, on the front end it just looks like refresh but on the backend there is definitely something not plugging in.

I cleared all the doctrine caches, composer caches and bin/console caches.

The files I have checked multiple times.

**.env**

```
 # This file is a "template" of which env vars need to be defined for your application
# Copy this file to .env file for development, create environment variables when deploying to production

###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=e239b1ba76d53407cbae30849fc489b9
#TRUSTED_PROXIES=127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2
#TRUSTED_HOSTS=localhost,example.com
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

###> symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ###
# For Gmail as a transport, use: "gmail://username:password@localhost"
# For a generic SMTP server, use: "smtp://localhost:25? encryption=&auth_mode="
# Delivery is disabled by default via "null://localhost"
MAILER_URL=null://localhost
###< symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine- 
dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# For an SQLite database, use: "sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# Configure your db driver and server_version in 
config/packages/doctrine.yaml

DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/symfony_test_db
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

**Security.yaml**

```
security:
encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    our_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: username
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: true
        provider: our_db_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login

    access_control:
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

**src/Entity/User.php**

```
 <?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, nullable=true)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=true)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=254, nullable=true)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
 */
private $isactive;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $apiKey;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->isActive = true;
    // may not be needed, see section on salt below
    // $this->salt = md5(uniqid('', true));
}

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getUsername(): ?string
{
    return $this->username;
}

public function setUsername(?string $username): self
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

public function getPassword(): ?string
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function setPassword(?string $password): self
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

public function getEmail(): ?string
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail(?string $email): self
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

public function getIsactive(): ?bool
{
    return $this->isactive;
}

public function setIsactive(?bool $isactive): self
{
    $this->isactive = $isactive;

    return $this;
}

public function getSalt()
{
    // you *may* need a real salt depending on your encoder
    // see section on salt below
    return null;
}

//Abstract methods implementation

public function getRoles()
{
    // TODO: Implement getRoles() method.
    return array('ROLE_USER');
}

public function eraseCredentials()
{
    // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
}

/** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        // see section on salt below
        // $this->salt,
    ));
}

/** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list (
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        // see section on salt below
        // $this->salt
        ) = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
}
}
```

**src/Repository/UserRepository.php**#

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

/**
 * @method User|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method User|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method User[]    findAll()
 * @method User[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class UserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
    parent::__construct($registry, User::class);
    }
}
```

**src/Controller/SecurityController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class SecurityController extends Controller {


public function index(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils) {

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error,
        )
    );
  }
}
```

**login.html.twig**

```
{% if error %}
<div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path('app_security_login') }}" method="post">
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username 
}}" />

<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

<button type="submit">login</button>
```

**user table schema**

```
id,username,password,is_active,email
```

**Edit Adding Routes.yml**

```
app_lucky_number:
   path: /lucky/number
   controller: App\Controller\LuckyController::index

app_security_login:
   path: /login
   controller: App\Controller\SecurityController::index
app_home:
   path: /
   controller: App\Controller\IBController::home
```

I am not sure as to what I have missed.

Comment: Could you please also add your `routes.yaml`?

Comment: Where have you defined your routes? routes.yaml? It seems to miss the login route definition here.

Comment: It might be because your login form submits to the route `app_security_login` whereas your security.yaml has `login` as check_path

Comment: Added security.yaml

Comment: So change `login_path: app_security_login` and `check_path: app_security_login` as @dbrumann suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you people commenting the question section, the error was simply in the `security.yaml` file.

At the `login_path` and `check_path` associate them with the name of the path and not the actual path.

So to rectify I changed

```
login_path: app_security_login
check_path: app_security_login
```